# How to optimise finding factors of a factorial

Tags: algorithm, optimization, factorial, prime-factoring

A part of the question that I am solving needs to find number of factors of a factorial of a number. The psuedocode for what I tried goes this way.

```
x = 2
ans = 1
while(x < n):    # n is given number
    if(isPrime(x)):
        count = 0
        temp = x
        while(temp < n):
            count += n/temp
            temp *= x
        ans *= (count+1)
    x += 1
```

But according to constraints, n could have a value up to 10^8. How can I optimise it?

Comment: I am confused by your pseudocode. You do nothing if the term in the factorial expansion is not prime, and you count up sum(n/x,n/x^2,n/x^3...)) if it is prime, and multiply the answer by one more than that. I simply cannot see how that relates to prime factorization, or any kind of factorization that I know of. Could you clarify what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

These optimizations work both for finding prime factors and all the factors of a factorial.

Using a sieve, it is easier to get a list of primes than to check each number to see if it is prime. The new pseudocode would be:

```
ans = 0
foreach(x in primes):
    if(x>n) break    # n is given number
    temp = x
    while(temp < n):
        ans += n/temp
        temp *= x
```

Second, note that the inner loop computes sum(n/x,n/x^2,n/x^3...) This can be rewritten, although the savings are minimal.

```
ans = 0
foreach(x in primes):
    if(x>n) break    # n is given number
    integer temp = n/x
    while(temp>0):
        ans += temp
        temp /= x
```